# iOS Application Rejection ( Subscription ) Metadata Rejected

Tags: ios, iphone

Missing In App Purchase
We are unable to complete the review of your app because your Free Subscription has not been submitted for review.

So that we can continue the review, please submit your Free Subscription AND upload a new binary in iTunes Connect. Learn more about submitting In App Purchases for review in the In-App Purchase Configuration Guide for iTunes Connect.

Once you've submitted your In-App Purchases and uploaded a new binary, we can proceed with your review

Details

Furthermore, we noticed that your Application Description did not fully meet the terms and conditions for auto-renewing subscriptions, as specified in Schedule 2, Section 3.8(b). Meeting the terms of this agreement is required by the App Store Review Guidelines.

Specifically, your Application Description did not include:

- the length of the subscription
- the price of the subscription
- information about the auto-renewable nature of the subscription
- links to the privacy policy and terms of use

Next Steps

Please revise your Application Description to include the missing information. For your convenience, we've includedSchedule 2, section 3.8(b) below.

"You clearly and conspicuously disclose to users the following information regarding Your auto-renewing subscription:

- Title of publication or service
- Length of subscription (time period and/or number of deliveries during each subscription period)
- Price of subscription, and price per issue if appropriate
- Payment will be charged to iTunes Account at confirmation of purchase
- Subscription automatically renews unless auto-renew is turned off at least 24-hours before the end of the current period
- Account will be charged for renewal within 24-hours prior to the end of the current period, and identify the cost of the renewal
- Subscriptions may be managed by the user and auto-renewal may be turned off by going to the user's Account Settings after purchase
- No cancellation of the current subscription is allowed during active subscription period
- Links to Your Privacy Policy and Terms of Use
- Any unused portion of a free trial period, if offered, will be forfeited when the user purchases a subscription to that publication."

Since your iTunes Connect Application State is Rejected, a new binary will be required. Make the desired metadata changes when you upload the new binary.

NOTE: Please be sure to make any metadata changes to all App Localizations by selecting each specific localization and making appropriate changes.

Missing restore mechanism

Additionally, we found that your app offers In-App Purchase(s) that can be restored but does not include a “Restore Purchases" feature to allow users to restore the previously purchased In-App Purchase(s), as specified in the “Restoring Purchase Products” section of the In-App Purchase Programming Guide

"Users restore transactions to maintain access to content they’ve already purchased. For example, when they upgrade to a new phone, they don’t lose all of the items they purchased on the old phone. Include some mechanism in your app to let the user restore their purchases, such as a Restore Purchases button."

To restore previously purchased In-App Purchase products, it would be appropriate to provide a "Restore" button and initiate the restore process when the "Restore" button is tapped by the user.

Comment: Ok, so this is the rejection from Apple. What's your question?

Comment: Yes  ... This message By Apple . Working Fine in Our Device

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not programming question. Just question about Apple's app submission problem

Comment: @sage444 is there a more appropriate place for app submission problems on Stack Exchange?

Comment: @DmitryIsaev I'm sure that first place for this kind of problems is Apple's developer support. And don't forget that documentation is on the zeroth place:)

Comment: @sage444 the docs on this issue are really unclear. Apple employees just wrote to me, "Your app's metadata did not include..." - what metadata?.. But the RobotBoy's answer below seems to be the solution.

Comment: @DmitryIsaev it's great that you found solution, and "metadata" in this contexts means: all information entered in iTunes Connect (app description, in app purchases, everything)

Answer (score 8):

Go with something like this:

**One Month Subscription**

Get unlimited downloads with no ads and stay hidden from friends. Subscription is auto-renewable which means that once purchased it will be auto-renewed every month until you cancel it 24 hours prior to the end of the current period. Duration  of the subscription is 1 Month with a charge of $3.99 every month. iTunes Account will be charged for renewal within 24-hours prior to the end of the current period with the cost of $3.99. Manage your Subscription and Auto-Renewal by going to your Account Settings.

**Terms of Service**

http://myapp.com/terms_of_service

**Privacy Policy**

http://myapp.com/privacy_policy

**Guidelines**

http://myapp.com/guidelines

Also add Privacy Policy URL to **App Information**.

Answer (score 2):

I have just gone through at least a full week of daily back and forth interaction with the reviewers..

I documented it in a medium article named [iOS Meta Data Rejected](https://medium.com/@salibsamer/ios-meta-data-rejected-b5bc6a4ea42b)

Here is the summary of it all:

- You need to include three pieces of information in two locations:

  1. in your app sign-on process (when the user is about to make a
     purchase from the app).

     **IN ADDITION TO**
  2. At the end of the app description
     paragraph in the App Store.

Namely:

1. A URL to your Terms and Conditions.
2. A URL to your privacy statement.
3. A paragraph to copy from the Apple developer documentation that [Clearly Describe your Subscription](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/subscriptions/#clear-description)

- Finally, you need to include the duration of each subscription next to the subscription name, as in the first screenshot on [Apple's Auto-Renewal Subscriptions documentation](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/subscriptions/)

For example, change a subscription name from "Ultimate Pro" to "Ultimate Pro (1 month)"

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you only submitted the file for review but you haven't submitted the InAppPurchases for review as well, so Apple can't continue with the review process.
When you submit an app that offers in app purchases for review, you need to also submit the purchasable items for review. Otherwise, the review team won't be able to carry on with the review process.

As they mention in their rejection letter, what you need to do now is submit a new binary and make sure (it's a part of the app's submission page on iTunes Connect) to also add the in app purchase items for review.

Comment: Please Review http://a293.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple6/v4/8a/e4/cd/8ae4cdc2-c3f7-b63e-dd45-9a825ce0f73b/pr_source.png?downloadKey3=1440261681_f5257a3c0f4e34fb58d6f68917af576a

Comment: You're looking at the wrong place. In the app page itself. Below the description, next to where you select the binary to submit for review, you have a section in which you can select all of the in app purchase items to submit for review with this version of the app. There, you can select all items that are in the "Waiting for Review" state.